# Python: pass a keypress to a bash program (less)

Tags: macos, bash, python-2.7

I needed a way to view my python IRC server's log from SSH (as a replacement for viewing the server's actual output. I don't want to use `screen`.), so I wrote a python script to `cat` the log file's contents forever. This worked will on the server computer, but flickered whenever it updated on my phone (which is the device I wrote this script for in the first place).

```
import time
import subprocess
#-----
while True:
    subprocess.call("cat chatLog.log", shell=True)
    time.sleep(1)
```

So, I decided to use `less`, which shows files in a more nano-like format (with scrolling. I'm not sure how else to describe it). I used this line:

```
subprocess.call("less -j-1 chatLog.log", shell=True)
```

The man pages say that -jn (no spaces) should make `less` start at line n. It also says, unless I'm misreading it, that negative numbers use the end of the file as a starting point, making -1 the last line and -2 the second to last. I found out that pressing `G` goes to the end of the file, and that `R` refreshes the file. I want to make python pass 'G' and 'R' to less at intervals. How could I do this, or what are some better ways to go about refreshing the file and seeking the last line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most people would use `tail -f` for this, e.g.:

```
tail -f chatLog.log
```

No need for a Python script at all.

Comment: Perfect! Does exactly what I wanted, and doesn't flicker on my phone. (Theoretically, because it isn't printing everything over and over again.)